# Tensorflow: How to change y_true tensor to numpy

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics

I was making my custom accuracy function to use in metrics

```
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse', metrics=[acc])
```

And in function acc, I tried to use input data as numpy

```
def acc (y_true, y_pred):

    print(y_true.getitem[0])

    ...

    return acc
```

I tried to use `tf.Tensor.getitem` but it doesn't worked, and I can't find useful example

If I print y_true

```
Tensor("ExpandDims:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32
```

Comment: Try `y_true = y_true.numpy()` if you want to convert a tensor to a numpy array.

Comment: I did it but it prints `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Comment: I don't think that you can not use numpy in custom accuracy functions. At least you can not use them in custom loss - because of the loss function is a part of graph and numpy can not backpropagate gradients. Custom accuracy is probably a part of graph as well

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for clarification, that makes sense.

Comment: 100% agree with @Andrey